# Passing an onClick javascript function when crafting an mvc link

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some hyperlinks which have a common class name. This hyperlinks are created dynamically on my web page with mvc asp.net helpers.
Right now I want to write a script that would determine the particular link that was clicked and execute a javascript function when this link is clicked.
My code is below.

My mvc code that generate the link, please take note of the function passed updateWaitingState(this)

```
td> @AntiXss.HtmlEncode(customerchatname) @Html.ActionLink("chat", "StartChat", new { threadid = avisitor.ThreadID, email = AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(email) }, htmlAttributes: new { target = "_blank", @class = "chat", operatorid = avisitor.OperatorID, connectionid = AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(connectionid), threadid = avisitor.ThreadID, onClick = "updateWaitingState(this);" })</td>
```

My javascript function for this link is below, JQuery has been called above the link.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     function updateWaitingState(sender) {

            var parentid = $(sender).attr("data-parentid");
            alert(parentid);

        }

    </script>
```

The problem is that the browser generates an undefined for the sender object. I have tried for hours debugging, I cant seem to find the problem.

When I run my code in the browser. The html looks like this

```
<tr id="kayode@yahoo.com">
                    <td> kayode <a class="chat" connectionid="135976e6-799b-4cda-a764-a00f7110d515" href="/Visitor/StartChat?threadid=3&amp;email=kayode%40yahoo.com" onclick="updateWaitingState(this);" operatorid="1" target="_blank" threadid="3">chat</a></td>
                    <td>271.0.0.1</td>
                    <td>Waiting</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>9/13/2014</td>
                    <td>04:15:18</td>
                    <td>00:00:10</td>
                    <td>271.0.0.1</td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: Don't use onclick attribute.

why dont you use

$('body').delegate(".myclass","click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); 
updateWaitingState(this);
})

Comment: Ok, thanks alot. Are you saying that I should remove the onClick='UpdateWaitingState(this)' in the anchor tag.

Comment: yes, use event listeners http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ or http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: the html which is generating is incorrect instead of onclick="updateWaitingState(sender);" it should be onclick="updateWaitingState(this);"

Comment: ok, I would change it now

Comment: I am looking into the code. Just a minute

Comment: its working see here http://jsfiddle.net/nm1L88u3/

Comment: Sorry I change the html code. I pasted the wrong code. The right one as the this as a parameter.

Comment: I have seen your fiddler post. The problem is I not given the roles id  at run time. because of the way I am generating them is quite difficult given them ids. So that is why I gave a common class

Comment: I suspect that its not `sender` that `undefined`, rather `parentid` because you have not rendered the attribute `data-parentid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not `sender` that undefined, its the value of `parentid` because the html for your action link does not have a `data-parentid` attribute. Modify the html to

```
@Html.ActionLink(..., htmlAttributes: new { ... data-parentid="SomeValue", onClick = "updateWaitingState(this);" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `anchor` tag a unique `id` say `'a1'` and try this :

```
document.getElementById('a1').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).data('parentid'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nm1L88u3/)

---

**EDIT :-** if you want to add event listener on class then do as :

```
document.querySelector('[class=chat]').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).data('parentid'));
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nm1L88u3/2/)

---

OR Try Pure Jquery Approach :-

```
$("a[class='chat']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).data('parentid'));
});
```

and make sure that there is a `attribute` i.e `data-parentid` in your anchor tag.

Comment: This would work. But I am not giving the an id at run time. I tried using the .getElementsByClassName('chat').addEventListener but it did not work

Comment: I just tried you querySelector option. I would tell you what I noticed  , doesnt work in my project. I went to fiddler and I discovered that wen the role is more than one containing that chat class. It would only work for the first role and not work for the second role. I verified this on fiddler.

Comment: @user3576600...if you are using jquery in your project then handle click with jquery as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I had to correct this html that I generated. The problem was not from the javascript rather the html.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("StartChat", new { threadid = avisitor.ThreadID, email = AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(email) })" class="chat" target="_blank" data-parentid="@AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(email)" onclick="updateWaitingState(this);">chat</a>
```

This solved the problem. Thanks alot for all your contributions. I really appreciate !!!!.

Comment: Is that exactly my answer?

Comment: yes, it looks like you answer anyway. I would click it right for you.